# Extract date stamp from filename and insert into Date Taken meta (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, command-line-interface

I have a lot of image files on Windows 10 named 'IMG-20180827-WA0001.jpg' and I would like to extract the date '20180827' and insert it into the 'Date taken' field as '27/08/2018' for those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I couldn't find a script nor how to create one to do what I was looking for.

What I was able to do was a multiple selection of files, right click and change the 'Date taken' field for all those files.